# Print without showing Print Preview on chrome

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I found a way to print without showing Print Preview on chrome like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dgzHO8A6PU, because then I can use AutoIT to install the printer but when I run Selenium it still shows the Print Preview window. So I want to ask when I run selenium to open chrome what file exactly am I working with?
[[image]

[[image]

Comment: Please share your code trials

Comment: i open chrome with a simple selenium code: '    Dim cd As New ChromeDriver
    cd.Start
    cd.Get "https://www.google.com/"
    cd.Window.Maximize
    cd.ExecuteScript ("print()")'

Comment: Add the switch "disable-print-preview" to chrome and try.

Comment: Not here! Put it into the question. Here it is not readable. Put all your code trials there.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cd As New ChromeDriver    
cd.AddArgument "--disable-print-preview"
cd.Start
cd.Get "https://www.google.com/"
cd.Window.Maximize
cd.ExecuteScript ("print()")
```

Thank @AbiSaran